# Highcharts : x-Axis alignment to column chart

Tags: grid, alignment, highcharts

I have a problem with Highcharts, when trying to pisition the x-Axis tick marks according to the column data shown.

http://i1260.photobucket.com/albums/ii564/sl26179/ScreenShot002.png

I try to display data on quarter-hourly base of an entire day. The problem is, when I populate the chart. The first bar represents the 0:00h -> 0:15h timespan. But the grid and tick marks are display at the right of the column, which is not good.

What I try to achieve is that the "00:00" tick mark, vertical grid lines are aligned with the y-Axis, and that the data columns are aligned left of the tick mark instead of on the right.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thx

Comment: Could you please show your code for the chart generation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should declare your domain axis as dateAxis and write this:

dateaxis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.START);

Hope this helps